# Type trait to check if a type is readable from stream and MSVC

Tags: c++, type-traits

Recently I have come across [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758291/how-can-i-detect-if-a-type-can-be-streamed-to-an-stdostream) discussed `is_streamable` type trait. So I decided to implement my own version and come up with the next solution to check if the type can be read from `std::istream` or not:

```
template<typename, typename = void>
struct is_readable_from_stream_impl
    : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_readable_from_stream_impl<T, 
    std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<std::istream&>() >> std::declval<T>())>>
    : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_readable_from_stream :
    is_readable_from_stream_impl<T> {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr auto is_readable_from_stream_v = is_readable_from_stream<T>::value;
```

So far, so good. I added then a custom structure with overloaded `operator>>`:

```
struct readable {};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, readable&)
{
    return is;
}
```

and tested the type trait:

```
static_assert(is_readable_from_stream_v<readable&>);
static_assert(!is_readable_from_stream_v<readable>);
```

The checks were passed with both `gcc 8.2` and `clang 6.0.0`, but `MSVC` [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/riKpZX) the second assert.

I am wondering if I my implementation (or test) is incorrect or it is another issue with `MSVC`.

Comment: Shouldn't the name of this trait be something like "is readable from stream using >> operator"? There are lots of other ways of reading from a stream.

Comment: @NeilButterworth it is a toy example, I didn't actually care about naming that much...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that MSVS can bind rvalues to lvalue-references as a language extension. The following code compiles:

```
struct readable{ };

void foo(readable&)
{ }

void bar()
{
    foo(readable{});
}
```

Use can use `/Za` option (Disable Language Extensions) to disable it. Then your asserts will be passed.

Comment: Ah, I guess it is a second or third time I forget about this wonderful extension. That is a good point!

Comment: I'd recommend using `/permissive-` if you can, rather than just `/Za`. It makes MSVC conform to the standard in many places that it doesn't normally do so.

Comment: Just to confirm - MSVS enables rvalues to lvalue-references *and* rvales to const-lvalue-references (which is standard)?

Comment: @Fureeish, yes, rvalues to lvalue-refs per an extension, rvalues to const-lvalue-refs per the Standard.