# Prevent instantiation of template class for types not supported by stringstream extraction operator (>>)

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, stringstream, enable-if

I'm trying to learn a bit about templates and metafunctions, namely `std::enable_if`. I'm making a menu system for our school assignments (extracurricular, mind you), and need a way of getting input from the user. I'd like to define a template class for various types of input - something used along the lines of:

```
std::string userInput = Input<std::string>("What's your name?").Show();
float userHeight = Input<float>("How tall are you?").Show();
```

I'd like to (and I'm sure there are reasons not to, but nevertheless) do this generalized sort of conversion using a `std::stringstream`: get input from user, feed into SS, extract into variable of type T.

It's easy enough to see if the conversion failed during runtime, but I'd like to use `std::enable_if` to prevent people from using my `Input<>` class for cases where conversion is impossible, say:

```
std::vector<Boats> = Input<std::vector<>>("Example").Show();
```

Obviously a `std::stringstream` cannot convert a string to a vector, so it will always fail.

## My question is this:

Can I format an `std::enable_if` clause to ONLY allow instantiation of my template class for the types listed above? Alternatively, is there a better way to go about it? Have I got things completely the wrong way around?

### What I've done so far

I believe I have found a list of allowed types that `std::stringstream` can "convert" a string into:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

I've been using `std::enable_if` like this up until this point:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename 
std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
```

However, now I'd like to extend it to allow not only arithmetic values, but all values supported by the sstream `>>` operator.

Comment: Why can't you convert a string into a vector?  It's pretty trivial to write stream operators to convert a vector to a string and back.  If the operator is not defined then you'll get a compiler error anyway so SFINAE really doesn't gain you anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver This is kind of the reason I've been needing help - if the stream operator is extended, it would be nice if my Input function allowed the extension seamlessly. Otherwise I could perhaps have filtered allowed types manually, but that seems like a bad walkaround. You're right that a compiler error will arise from using it wrong, but I want to learn how to detect these things - perhaps with static_assert, to print a suitable error, rather than enable_if.

Comment: OK.  A `static_asset` is a different scenario than SFINAE.  SFINAE can still give you horrible error messages.  At least you got a couple answers that will let you use a `static_assert`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer to use a SFINAE with a class template parameter, then you want

```
template <
    typename T,
    typename = decltype(std::declval<std::istringstream &>() >> std::declval<T &>(), void())
>
class Input /*...*/
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are trying to use `std::enable_if` for something which doesn't require it. If your template function already relies on `operator<<` applied on a generic type `T`, then compilation will fail in any case if the operator is not specialized for that type.

Nothing prevents you from using `std::enable_if` to solve your specific problem, though that may be not the best way to do it.

If C++20 [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) were already largely adopted I'd say that that would be your way to go.

Comment: That makes sense, and you're probably right. Maybe static_assert is a better choice in this case, just so I can send a less confusing error message. But that still relies on a compile-time assertion, right? So I still need to perform some sort of validation on the input type?

Answer (score 0):

You could go the way as suggested here [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759544/4290866) and implement a class `is_streamable` which can check for that like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<typename S, typename T>
class is_streamable
{
    template<typename SS, typename TT>
    static auto test(int)
        -> decltype(std::declval<SS&>() << std::declval<TT>(), std::true_type());

    template<typename, typename>
    static auto test(...)->std::false_type;

public:
    static const bool value = decltype(test<S, T>(0))::value;
};

class C
{
public:
    friend std::stringstream& operator<<(std::stringstream &out, const C& c);
};

std::stringstream& operator<<(std::stringstream& out, const C& c)
{
    return out;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << is_streamable<std::stringstream, C>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This would return one if the operator is implemented and zero if not.

With that you can alter your snippet to

```
template <typename T, typename = typename 
std::enable_if<is_streamable<std::stringstream, C>::value, T>::type>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several thing you want:

- a trait, is_streamable
- a way to forbid class instantiation.

For the traits, you might use `std::experimental_is_detected` or run your own:

```
template <typename T>
auto is_streamable_impl(int)
-> decltype (T{},
             void(), // Handle evil operator ,
             std::declval<std::istringstream &>() >> std::declval<T&>(),
             void(), // Handle evil operator ,
             std::true_type{});

template <typename T>
std::false_type is_streamable_impl(...); // fallback, ... has less priority than int

template <typename T>
using is_streamable = decltype(is_streamable_impl<T>(0));
```

Then to forbid intantiation, several choices:

`static_assert`:

```
template <typename T>
class Input
{
    static_assert(is_streamable<T>::value);
    // ...
};
```

or SFINAE friendly class:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_streamable<T>>>
class Input
{
    // ...
};
```

so you allow to know if `Input<T1>` is valid.

Notice that without all that stuff, your program won't compile anyway when instantiating the problematic method (hard error, so no SFINAE friendly).

Being SFINAE friendly is not necessary most of the time.